# How to ensure MoltenVK compatibility of applications using Vulkan?

Tags: validation, vulkan, moltenvk

Is there any validation layer that validates Vulkan 1.1 compliance? Is there any convenient way to ensure that I'm not using Vulkan 1.2+ features?

## Update

Here is a related github thread: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK/issues/1533

It seems there are potential serious downsides to using Vulkan over Metal via MoltenVK (transcribe cost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application sets the `apiVersion` member of `VkApplicationInfo` to 1.1, the `VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation` layer will issue messages about any 1.2 usage.

Since you've mentioned MoltenVK, you may also want to look up information about the portability subset extension in the Vulkan specification.  In particular, I think you need to enable that extension if you are going to use MoltenVK and the extension provides the ability to query for non-conformant behavior.